# Multiple layouts + lazy loading in Angular

Tags: angular

I have worked on a couple of Angular applications already, but all of those were using one layout for the entire application.

I am now converting an application built with AngularJS + UI-Router to Angular 5. Using AngularJS + UI-Router it is quite easy to have the "master-page" independent from your route, but i dont immediately see how i can easily reproduce this with the Angular 5 router.

Also, i would like to keep the possiblity to use lazy-loading.

An example of what i would like to achieve:

```
"/" application root
"/routeA" -> lazily loaded module
"/routeA/routeA01" -> default layout with header, footer, sidebar
"/routeA/routeA02" -> alternate layout with completely different html as used in route above
```

Comment: Did you think about usage of modules and `forRoot()` or `forChild()` ? https://medium.com/@cyrilletuzi/understanding-angular-modules-ngmodule-and-their-scopes-81e4ed6f7407

Comment: I know what those methods are for, but i dont see how  they would solve this problem? Can you elaborate?

Comment: I guess your `/routeA/routeA01` and `/routeA/routeB01` are child routes of parents module `/routeA/routeA` and `/routeA/routeB`. Aren't they ?

Comment: I edited the example to be a bit less confusing. In this example, /routeA would lazily load ModuleA, which has 2 child routes begin routeA01 and routeA02

Comment: Could you add a draw with your layout, please (or a xml-like structure) ? I agree with @rmcsharry's edited answer : what is shared between routeA's pages and what is shared between all pages (maybe at least a header with a navbar, no)

Answer (score 3):

Yes this is possible.

You need a parent module, let's call it Pages module. It can have a Pages Component that has your main page layout:

```
pages.component.ts
pages.component.html
```

The pages html template is just this, so you don't really need a separate file, you could just declare it in the ts file:

```
    <div class="main">
        <router-outlet></router-outlet>
    </div>
```

This component is loaded in your pages module:

\src\app\pages\pages.module.ts

```
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { CommonModule } from '@angular/common';
import { PagesComponent } from './pages.component';

@NgModule({
  imports: [
    CommonModule,
    routing    
  ],
  declarations: [ 
    PagesComponent,
  ]
})
export class PagesModule { }
```

The pages module has a corresponding routes file (you could just declare the routes in the above file). In this example I am showing 2 lazy loaded modules, routeA and routeB:

\src\app\pages\pates.routing.ts

```
import { Routes, RouterModule } from '@angular/router';
import { ModuleWithProviders } from '@angular/core';    
import { PagesComponent } from './pages.component';

export const routes: Routes = [
    {
        path: '',
        component: PagesComponent,
        children: [
            { path: 'routeA', loadChildren: 'app/pages/routeA/routeA.module#RouteAModule'},
            { path: 'routeB', loadChildren: 'app/pages/routeB/routeB.module#RouteBModule'},
        ]
    }
];

export const routing: ModuleWithProviders = RouterModule.forChild(routes);
```

Finally the RouteA module, with routes declared as part of the module file:

\src\app\pages\routeA\routeA.module.ts

```
import { NgModule, Component } from '@angular/core';
import { RouterModule } from '@angular/router';
import { CommonModule } from '@angular/common';

import { RouteA01Component } from './routeA01/routeA01.component.ts';
import { RouteA02Component } from './routeA02/routeA02.component.ts';   

export const routes = [
  { path: 'routeA01', component: RouteA01Component },
  { path: 'routeA02', component: RouteA02Component },
];

@NgModule({
  declarations: [
    RouteA01Component, 
    RouteA02Component, 
  ],
  imports: [
    CommonModule,
    RouterModule.forChild(routes);
  ],
  providers: [
  ]
})
export class RouteAModule { }
```

Notice that RouteA01 and RouteA02 are separate routes and separate components that can contain completely different html and css.

**EDIT**

Reading your question again I think it is a bit ambiguous because you say that you want RouteA01 to load a default layout with header, menu, sidebar. Normally you would put that into PagesComponent, then put `<router-outlet>` where you want the content to differ. This way both RouteA01 and RouteA02 will get the same 'default' header, menu, sidebar but the main content inside that will change based on which route and child component are loaded.

However, if you want RouteA02 to have a completely different layout (ie different header, menu, sidebar) then you can do it exactly as I have shown above and both RouteA01 and RouteA02 components would declare their different header, menu and sidebar.

Comment: This is how you setup lazy loading. But what im actually trying to do is having 2 different versions of "pages.component.html", and have different routes use those different versions.

Comment: According to your question you want a lazy loaded module, with two child routes that can load different versions. That's exactly what the above code will do. 'Pages' component can be your AppComponent - and essentially is just a holder into which you load either layout A01 or A02 (lazily) depending upon which route is visited. So it will appear that 'Pages' is 2 different versions.

Answer (score 0):

Let's say there are 2 feature pages

1. One has - header, footer and content in the middle.
2. The other has - header, article, content, but no footer.

The feature pages will be routed to and shown using unamed Router Outlet `<router-outlet>`. Which encompasses the whole website.

And the layout specific routing, i.e. Auxiliary Routing, should be done using named Router Outlet `<router-outlet name="aside">`. Which take up small sections of the whole available screen real-estate. Even pop ups should be done this way!

Checkout: [One Hungry Mind](https://www.concretepage.com/angular-2/angular-2-4-named-router-outlet-popup-example) & [Auxiliary Routing Tut](https://angular-2-training-book.rangle.io/handout/routing/aux-routes.html) for a better understanding.